# why wrong data stored in firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

What went wrong? The data stored in firebase database are all wrong, which are totally different with my inputs in EditTexts.

```
public void createToUserProfile(){
        String firstName = etFirstName.toString().trim();
        String lastName = etLastName.toString().trim();
        String mobilePhoneNumber = etMobilePhoneNumber.toString().trim();
        String iDNumber = etIDNumber.toString().trim();
        String year = etYear.toString().trim();
        String month = etMonth.toString().trim();
        String day = etDay.toString().trim();
        String dateOfBirth = year+"/"+month+"/"+day;
        String country = etCountry.toString().trim();
        String province = etProvince.toString().trim();
        String city = etCity.toString().trim();
        String postCode = etPostCode.toString().trim();
        String address = etAddress.toString().trim();

        Firebase ref = new Firebase(Config.USER_URL);
        UserP newUser = new UserP();

        newUser.setFirstName(firstName);
        newUser.setLastName(lastName);
        newUser.setMobilePhoneNumber(mobilePhoneNumber);
        newUser.setiDNumber(iDNumber);
        newUser.setDateOfBirth(dateOfBirth);
        newUser.setCountry(country);
        newUser.setProvince(province);
        newUser.setCity(city);
        newUser.setPostCode(postCode);
        newUser.setAddress(address);
        ref.child("UserP").setValue(newUser);
}
```

The Firebase Console stored data shows as following:
[Data stored wrong in Firebase Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLrv5.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I recall this same issue from a previous post of yours.

An `EditText` has a [toString()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#toString()) method inherited from `View` that returns a string dump of the view's properties.  You are mistakenly calling that.  To get  the string the `EditText` contains, you need to call [getText().toString()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getText()).

Comment: Great Thanks! Problem solved.